# geoip2 trial is always saying OUT_OF_QUERIES

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I have created a trial account at https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-country-service

Even though they say that I can refresh the page up to 1000 times using a trial account, it doesn't allow me to reload the page atleast once and I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'GeoIp2\Exception\OutOfQueriesException' with message 'The license key
>   you have provided is out of queries. Please log in to your account at
>   http://www.maxmind.com to add queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the Web Service and your "Account Summary" page says "GeoIP2 Precision: City" then the trial account accepts only the "city" in the URI, but doesn't accept the "country".

Please use the "city" in the URI (or call the method "city" in your programming language API instead of "country").

If you are using the JavaScript Client API, then probably this answer isn't appropriate - I have not worked with that API.

Answer (score 0):

Does the method you are calling match the query type that you have? If you have Country queries, as your post suggests, you should be calling `->country($ip)` (as opposed to `->insights()` or `->city()`).